# configuration for TLS implementation on Jboss 5.1

Tags: security, ssl, tls1.2, jboss5.x

I have Jboss 5.1 server on which , I have to implement the TLS security. If possible TLSv1.2.

Currently using SSL , want it to be upgraded to TLS.

Tried digging out through Jboss guide and other sites , but could not find anything solid on this. Found something like this but seems it is not working -

```
<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" 
port="8543" address="${jboss.bind.address}" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" 
keystoreFile="/opt/novell/idm/jre/bin/mycert.keystore"
keystorePass="mypassword" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" 
ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_W ITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_W ITH_RC4_128_SHA,
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_1 28_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA" />
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I *think* you're likely already using TLS.  Do you have access to open ssl like from a linux/unix box.  If you do, run this command replacing domain.com with the real domain name of your server and put the results/output in your question `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect domain.com:8443  </dev/null` also, change the port if its not 8443

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplified version, I do see that according to Red Hat, you're missing the SSLProtocol attribute and value.

```
<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" 
       port="8443" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
       scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" 
       keystoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/keystore.jks"
       keystorePass="password" sslProtocols = "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" />
```

That might not be an issue though because according to the SO post [how to make jboss 5.1.0 ga meet diffie hellman standards](https://serverfault.com/questions/721489/how-to-make-jboss-5-1-0-ga-meet-diffie-hellman-standards) as I said in my comment, you're likely already using TLS and don't realize it.  The openSSL test should show you are.

**Update** on the `sslProtocols = "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"`, I'd recommend going with just TLSv1.2 for security unless you have clients that absolutely have to have older versions.

Comment: it worked with slight modification  -  

   <Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" 
           port="8443" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
           scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" 
           keystoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/keystore.jks"
           keystorePass="rmi+ssl"
           sslProtocols = "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" />

no need to add cipher - let the server and client decide that part

Comment: Glad you got it working - I'll update the answer with the modification you made if you want to accept it!

Comment: @AshishShetkar, glad I could help you get it going.  Have a good one!